# How to access model array by index in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I am unable to access the EmberArray by index in the template. This is part of my route

```
model(){
  return RSVP.hash({
    games: this.store.findAll('game')
  })
}
```

And this is part of the template

```
<div>
  First game: {{model.games.[0].name}}
</div>
```

There is **no output** that is rendered. Although if I iterate over it using

```
{{#each model.games as |game|}}
  <div>{{game.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

This works fine. Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or what I should do different ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firstObject method.

```
{{model.games.firstObject.name}}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that worked. And any idea how I can access the second element ?

Comment: You can create computed property and use it in template.
secondGame: Ember.computed('model.games', function { 
return this.get('model.games').objectAt(1);
}

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have done this for now. Seemed like the cleanest way.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to iterate over all of items and if you don't mind composing a bit of logic dierctly in the template, [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) addon might come useful, for example accessing a concrete item in a given array using [object-at](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#object-at), from the docs:

> Returns the object at the given index of an array.

Notation:

`{{object-at index array}}`

which (in a case you want to show a name of the second item) would be:

`{{object-at 1 model.games}}`

Comment: This looks interesting thanks. And how would I access a property on the given object ? {{(object-at 1 model.games).name}} ?

Comment: You could use the [get](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get) helper. 
`{{get (object-at 1 model.games) 'name'}}`
Nothing limits you in composing template helpers altogether. Take a look at another example from the ember-composable-helpers docs:
`{{take 5 (sort-by "lastName" "firstName" (filter-by "active" array))}}`. Hence the name **composable** :) Isn't that beautiful? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper. Something like this:

```
// app/helpers/array-index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function ([array, index]) {
  return array !== undefined && array[index] !== undefined ? array[index] : undefined;
});
```

Use it together with get:

```
{{get (array-index model.games 1) 'name'}}
```

P.S. As we are talking about collection returned from Ember Data, that's may be not a pure js array, but something like [ArrayProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html). In this case you probably need to use it's method `objectAt`:

```
// app/helpers/array-index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function ([array, index]) {
  return array && array.objectAt ? array.objectAt(index) : (array && array[index]);
});
```

Comment: Oh this looks great! Thanks, might give this a shot.